# how to access input data submitted to ajax request (NOT return data) via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to retrieve the data I submitted to an asynchronous ajax request should the back-end fail in some way. The data in 'myJSONData' is actually pulled off a queue (array) in memory and I need to put it back into the queue if any kind of error occurs.

e.g.

```
var myJSONData = {"parm1":"value1","parm2":"value"};

$.ajax({
  type:     "POST",
  url:      "/postData.ajax",
  dataType: "json",
  data:     myJSONData,
  success:  function(jsonReply) {
              // I need to refer to the posted data here (i.e. myJSONData)
  },
  error:    function(xhr,ajaxOptions,thrownError) {
              // I need to refer to the posted data here (i.e. myJSONData)
  }
});
```

My code fires off a number of calls at various times, the trouble is that if I refer to myJSONData within the success or error blocks it contains the most recent value of that variable in memory, and not what was in the variable at the time of the ajax call.

Is there some other way to access the data associated with the particular instance of ajax call - something like $.ajax.data ?

Comment: Just my sure that `myJSONdata` is not shared between calls, e.g. by passing the object as argument to the function. Also note that the variable name is misleading, since it doesn't hold JSON but an object.

Comment: you need to store the same in some local variable with limited scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access it in your success and error functions :

```
success: function(jsonReply) {
    var p1 = myJSONData.param1;
}
```

Comment: you are so very right. My actual code wasn't quite how I'd posted it -  the posted data was actually JSON.stringify(scoreObject), rather than a variable. Having done the stringify first, I can now access the original parameters via the object variable as you say.  thanks!